# The idempotent elements of Eisenstein Integers

Tags: idempotents, eisenstein-integers

Let a+bω be an Eisenstein integer.
An idempotent element of $ \mathbb Z_n[\omega]$ is $(a+b\omega)^2 \equiv (a+b\omega)\pmod{n} $, where $\omega^2=-\omega-1$
But it follows that the idempotent element of this ring is always idempotent if and only if a is an element of n and b is equal to zero. Im having problems on proving this statement is true.

Comment: My friend told me that I should try proving by example but im not satisfied proving that way

Comment: Don't bother with friends here; just compute. How do you define $\mathbb{Z}_n[\omega]$? Certainly $\omega\not\in \mathbb{Z}_n$. Isn't this the same question as [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648686/proving-the-idempotent-elements-of-eisenstein-integers)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving the idempotent elements of Eisenstein Integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648686/proving-the-idempotent-elements-of-eisenstein-integers)

Answer (score 1):

Expand $(a + wb)^2 - (a+b)$ to get the following:

$$(2ab - b)w + a2 - 2b - a \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$$

If $b \equiv 0$ and $a \equiv 0$ Then the above statement is true and so $(a+bw)$ is idempotent.

Comment: I'm sorry there was a mistake in my statement, that should  be
$(a+b\omega)^2 \equiv (a+b\omega)\pmod{n}$  
So, as you said if I expand $(a+b\omega)^2-(a+b\omega)$ I'll get $a^2-b^2-a+(2ab-b^2-b)\omega \equiv 0\pmod{n}$  I was trying to assume that $a=a^2-b^2$ and $b=2ab-b^2$ and then getting the modulo of each term, $(a^2-b^2)\pmod{n}$ and $(2ab-b^2)\pmod{n}$